# Create a widget to display image and Title?

Tags: widgets

I want to Create a Widget with image top and Title at bottom.Please help me to display

[image]

like image top and Title at bottom also add link to to the arrow image.

i have Created a Widget area and installed "image widget",can display image using "image widget" but the problem is i cannot display the Title at bottom and add links to the Title.

Comment: What have you tried so far. What code do you have and where are you getting stuck. Please edit your question and add your code and effort. Your question is also very broad. You are not stating where the images/posts will be generated from, is it category posts, custom post types...???

Comment: Created a Widget area and installed "image widget",can display image using "image widget" but the problem is i cannot display the Title at bottom and add links to the Title.

Comment: You should edit your question and add this information to your question

Comment: You know that an [Image Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/) already exists right?